# Fill SharedArrayBuffer with objects

Tags: node.js, service-worker, shared-memory, worker

My application receives data from external sources and groups it (matching group items and shows result as HTML table, up to 20k msg/sec).

The problem is shared memory: application works in real time, I receive messages with flags "create, update, delete" so I store all in RAM, no need for any database. But when I try clustering my application messages are missed for some clusters (I tried cluster with **pm2**).

So now I am trying to scale my application with WorkerThreads, but communication via `parentPort.postMessage/worker.postMessage` requires a lot of changes to the application. So now I am trying to share memory via `SharedArrayBuffer`, but I don't understand how to share an array of objects between master and workers.

```
const {
  Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData
} = require('worker_threads');

if (isMainThread) {
  const sab = new SharedArrayBuffer(1024);
  sab[0] = {foo: 'bar'};
  const worker = new Worker(__filename, {
    workerData: sab
  });

  setInterval(() => {
   console.log( sab[0] ); // always {foo: 'bar'}
  }, 500);

} else {
  let sab = workerData;
  sab.foo = false; // changing "foo" value at worker but not in main thread
}

setInterval(() => {}, 1000);
```